# XML data type cannot be compared or sorted

Tags: sql-server, order-by, xml, snowflake

My source is in SQL server; my target is in Snowflake. The target table was created by extracting the XML column only from the source. I need to compare the first 20 rows in source and target to see if the data matches. I need the 20 rows to be in the same order. I queried the source in SQL Server with this:

```
SELECT TOP 20
COLUMN_XML
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY COLUMN_XML;
```

I received this error message:

> The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the
> IS NULL operator.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if I can query the top 20 rows in the XML column in source and target in a way so they are in the same order?

Comment: Although I could query a second column in the source, and order by that, I can't query the same additional column in the target because the target contains only the XML column and no other columns.

Comment: When I posted my question, I used shift return to break my SQL query into four lines rather than one. But when I posted it, it changed that back to one line. How do I ensure my code will be displayed in multiple lines when it is posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### overall

This seems like a really bad design choice. It would be wiser to parse out the XML into proper normalized tables to compare. XML is just one of those redheaded data types that has a lot more restrictions on it than others.

You can use the below examples to do what you want, but it's probably going to perform absolutely terrible.

```
DECLARE 
    @t table (x xml);

INSERT 
    @t
(
    x
)
VALUES
(
    N'<x>x</x>'
);    

SELECT TOP (1) 
    t.x 
FROM @t AS t
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), t.x) IN 
    (
        SELECT
            CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), t2.x)
        FROM @t AS t2
    )
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), t.x);
```

I'd seriously re-think this approach if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if I can query the top 20 rows in the XML column

Highly unlikely because SQLServer is saying "No".

XML is just a big block of text and trying to sort by big blocks of text is likely to perform [very] badly.

XML is a composite data type.
It's made up of much smaller bits and it probably makes sense to sort by one [or more] of those "bits", rather than the whole thing.  As Erik says, you're probably better off normalising [at least some of] this into more sensible, Relational structures.

XML can also be a big "woolly" in its definition and/or implementation.
Attributes are officially *unordered* lists of key-value pairs so, while XML would consider these two as equivalent, sorting them *as text* would not!

```
<element1 attr1="value1" attr2="value2"/>
<element1 attr2="value2" attr1="value1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. This is helpful.